# como puedo almacenar una lista que llega de una consulta ORM por un this en un json C# .NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, .net, dotnetcore

HOLA hoy estuve haciendo unas pruebas para hacer un código de una tarea programada en c#, pero resulta que tenía que consultar la base de datos con un ORM : **ORM en cuestión**

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Innovations>> GenerateCronJops()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(_dbConnection))
        {
            IEnumerable<Innovations> listcronjops = await (from inv in db.Innovations
                                                                       select new Innovations
                                                                       {
                                                                           Title = inv.Title,
                                                                           Description = inv.Description,
                                                                           Problem = inv.Problem,
                                                                           Solution = inv.Solution,
                                                                           Scope = inv.Scope,
                                                                           Result = inv.Result,
                                                                       }).ToArrayAsync();
            return listcronjops;
        }


    }
```

ahora esto lo llamo desde el archivo al cual traigo lo que trae esta **ORM** como devolución lo traigo con un **this** de la siguiente manera

```
 public void datajson()
    {
        this._innovationRepository.GenerateCronJops();
    }
```

¿cuál es el tema de esto es que luego tengo que general un JSON como archivo y cabe agregar que el archivo se estará generando cada cierto tiempo, pero este se debe sobrescribir y no tengo muy consiente de como hacer eso, alguien sabe como lo puedo hacer??

***Todo el código de la función programada actualmente:***

```
public class intervalTaskHostservice : IHostedService
{
    private IInnovationRepository _innovationRepository;
    private Timer _timer;
    

    public intervalTaskHostservice(IInnovationRepository IInnovationRepository)
    {
        _innovationRepository = IInnovationRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(IInnovationRepository));
    }
    public void datajson()
    {
        this._innovationRepository.GenerateCronJops();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(saveFileJson, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void saveFileJson(object state)
    {
       
       // el generar el archivo json en los archivo iria aca y se tiene que sobreescribir 

    }
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes 3 funciones: Una para guardar, otra para leer y otra para obtener la ruta de la aplicación.

Cuando guarda sobrescribe que es lo que creo que estas pidiendo. Esto lo hace porque tiene como argumento FileMode.Create, es decir siempre lo crea. FileMode.OpenOrCreate lo crearía si no existe, pero si existe añadiría el contenido

```
  public async Task Guardar(object objeto, string nombre = "dato.json")
    {
        string PATH = $@"{GetPath()}\{nombre}";

        string texto = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objeto);
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(PATH, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writter = new StreamWriter(stream);
        await writter.WriteAsync(texto);
        await writter.FlushAsync();
        writter.Close();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetFromJson<T>(string nombre = "dato.json")
    {
        string PATH = $@"{GetPath()}\{nombre}";
        FileStream fParameter = new FileStream(PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(fParameter);
    }

    public static string GetPath() => Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Ejemplo de uso

```
await Guardar(_innovationRepository);
var p2 = await GetFromJson<<IEnumerable<Innovations>>>();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución, pero me surge una duda como yo le puedo pasar el this._innovationRepository.GenerateCronJops();

Comment: @ŦŁłPGΛMΞЯSHłPJUΛЛŦΞŁłPΞ Al final de la respuesta he puesto un ejemplo. Recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta si te parece adecuado. Saludos!!

Comment: Saludos, claro que sí, pero al parecer marca un error que desconozco el cual me dice que no y es que este json se va a generar cada cierto tiempo y me dice que no puedo convertir un void a objet, ya que al ser una función programada que se va a repetir en segundo plano cada cierto tiempo por lo cual el ejemplo no funciona se le pasa como parámetros object state como puedes ver en el codigo de arriba public async void saveFileJson(object state)

Comment: @ŦŁłPGΛMΞЯSHłPJUΛЛŦΞŁłPΞ Pensé que .GenerateCronJops() retornaba algo que seria lo logico, sacalo entonces  Guardar(_innovationRepository)

Comment: Por eso en el primer código hice una especificación de la función que realiza de ORM que es esa función GenerateCronJops()

Comment: bro la verdad estoy algo atorado y creo que sería más fácil solucionar esto por Discord si puedes te dejo mi id flipgamership#4901 feliz dia y saludos

Comment: @ŦŁłPGΛMΞЯSHłPJUΛЛŦΞŁłPΞ Estimado no sé qué estará haciendo mal, pero probé el asunto y funciona. Puedes poner dentro de tu función saveFileJson, esto await Guardar(this._innovationRepository.GenerateCronJops()); y te va a guardar el asunto volviendo a consultar los valores. Ahora no quieres volver a consultar pones: await Guardar(this._innovationRepository);

Comment: @ŦŁłPGΛMΞЯSHłPJUΛЛŦΞŁłPΞ Y te aclaro que lo probé con el timer y cada 10 segundo lo ejecuta correctamente